# How can I prevent hidden elements in a fixed scrollable list?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with a dropdown list. As you can see, the last scrollable element is hidden. When I remove the header, the last element is visible but not with the header. I can't find the problem because I don't understand whats happening here. This is already live on my page so maybe there is a small fix that handles everything. It would be hard to change the whole design.

This is my code:

```css
#dropdown-menu {
  height: 60%;
  display: block !important;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: unset; 
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.4rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

#header {
  padding-top: 28px;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 12px;
  touch-action: none;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  padding-top: 28px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#header::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 4px;
  width: 20px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 8px;
  top: 15px;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

#list {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: unset;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: relative;
}

#list .element {
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: gray;
}

#list .element:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropdown-menu">
  <div id="header">
    <span>Notifications</span>
  </div>
  <div id="list">
    <span class="element"></span>
    <span class="element"></span>
    <span class="element"></span>
    <span class="element"></span>
    <span class="element"></span>
    <span class="element"></span>
    <span class="element"></span>
    <span class="element"></span>
    <span class="element"></span>
    <span class="element"></span>
    <span class="element"></span>
    <span class="element"></span>
    <span class="element"></span>
    <span class="element"></span>
    <span class="element">Last element</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Hm, seems like you want a flex layout, but you aren't really using flex effectively yet... So what is your intent? Do you want to use flex to layout all the components in your `dropdown-menu`? And do you intend to use flex to layout your elements in `list` as well?

Comment: This might be a useful reference: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Does the below answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `height: calc(100% - 58px);` on `#list`

```css
#dropdown-menu {
  height: 60%;
  display: block !important;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: unset; 
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.4rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

#header {
  padding-top: 28px;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 12px;
  touch-action: none;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  padding-top: 28px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#header::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 4px;
  width: 20px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 8px;
  top: 15px;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

#list {
  height: calc(100% - 58px);
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: relative;
}

#list .element {
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: gray;
}

#list .element:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropdown-menu">
  <div id="header">
    <span>Notifications</span>
  </div>
  <div id="list">
    <span class="element"></span>
    <span class="element"></span>
    <span class="element"></span>
    <span class="element"></span>
    <span class="element"></span>
    <span class="element"></span>
    <span class="element"></span>
    <span class="element"></span>
    <span class="element"></span>
    <span class="element"></span>
    <span class="element"></span>
    <span class="element"></span>
    <span class="element"></span>
    <span class="element"></span>
    <span class="element">Last element</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes! Helped. Thanks.